# Kill all minecarts on a specific block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am working on my "Minecart Elevator" and I need to kill all the minecarts on a specific block. I have tried many methods, but none of them work. There is no track below the minecarts. How should I do this?

Comment: "Specific Block" as in "All minecarts on top of the block at x=50,y=64,z=-215" or "All Minecarts on top of cyan wool"?

Comment: All minecarts on top of the block at x=50,y=64,z=-215

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. At https://gist.github.com/Dinnerbone/3736487, there is information stating that to target entities at a block, you use:

```
@e[4,4,4,r=your_radius,type=MinecartRideable,tag=value...]
```

where 4,4,4 are your x y and z, and your_radius is your radius.

Comment: This will kill all minecarts in the world. Changing the origin only modifies the starting point of selection. You must also include an area limiter such as a radius: `@e[4,4,4,0,type=MinecartRideable,tag=value]`